# Como abrir um link em uma nova aba aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, link

Estou tentando abrir uma nova pagina em uma aba diferente, através aspx, eu consegui um código na internet que faz isso, porem, ele só funciona com clicks.

segue o código

```
LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('../conheca-os-alimentos-aprovacao.aspx');return false;");
```

Alguém pode me ajudar!

Comment: Amigo, eu não manjo nada de asp.net, porem seguindo a lógica do que postou, tente fazer o seguinte:

LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("href", "http://google.com.br");
LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");

Answer (score 3):

Na página ".aspx", sbstitiua os itens que tem acrescentando o "_target", isto na página, como segue:

```
  <asp:LinkButton runat="Server" ....  target="_blank"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 2):

Faça como o Luiz Vichiatto indicou ou...

Adicione o seguinte código:

```
LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('../conheca-os-alimentos-aprovacao.aspx');return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o código abaixo direto no LinkButton. Quando você especificou que só funciona com clicks, o que gostaria de fazer, então? Deseja que alguma regra de negócio interna da página abra uma nova aba? Poderia especificar melhor a pergunta?

**Obs:** Abrir nova aba ou nova janela sem a ação do usuário (sem o click) é considerado pop-up e bloqueado pelo navegador na maioria dos casos.

```
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="teste" ID="lnkTeste" OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.google.com');" target="_blank"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem duas maneiras práticas para abrir uma nova aba `.aspx`!

1. Utilizando um script dentro C#
   `Response.Write("<script>window.open(' Caixa.aspx','_blank'); </script>");`
2. Utilizando um atributo no elemento button
   `OnClientClick ="window.open('CAMINHO.aspx', '_blank'); return false;"/>"`